# Scipy optimize minimize - restrict the variable bounds to either 0 or 1

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to minimize the equation **x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]**.

let say, A = [5,3,8,6]

constraint Equation is **A1 x[0] + A2 x[1] + A3 x[2] + A4 x[3] = 11** where 0 <= x <= 1 and x should be integer(either 0 or 1).

Expected output for x is  [0,1,1,0]

Please help me to achieve this.

Please find below code what i have tried.

**code**:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#objective function definition
def objective(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]

#constraint definition
def constraint1(x):
    sum_eq = 11
    a = [5,3,8,6]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sum_eq = sum_eq - (a[i]*x[i])
    return sum_eq

#set the bounds
b = (0,1)
bnds = (b,b,b,b)
cons1 = {'type':'eq','fun':constraint1}

#initialisation
x0 = [0,0,0,1]

sol = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds, constraints=cons1)
print(sol.x)
```

**output**:

```
[3.53445929e-16 3.83487389e-17 1.00000000e+00 5.00000000e-01]
```

Comment: Do you have to use scipy.optimize? The constraint of x[i] == 0 or 1 seems to indicate that a simple brute force approach can be used, as there are only 2^4 possible combination for the x array.

Comment: yes. I achieved this using PuLP. I need to get the same using scipy.optimize.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can use [`fmin_slsqp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html). First you need to define function that will return `0` from you equation. Then evaluate function with parameters to find solution with declared bounds.

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp
import numpy as np


def zero_equation(x):
    return (x*np.array([5,3,8,6])).sum()-11


def function(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]


b = (0,1)
bounds = (b,b,b,b)
starting_parameters = np.array([0,0,0,1])
result = fmin_slsqp(function, x0=starting_parameters , bounds=bounds ,eqcons=[zero_equation])
```

**Output:**

```
[0.  0.  1.  0.5]
```

Comment: Thank you. But i was expecting only integer values in the output (0 or 1).
Ex: [0,1,1,0] is also equals to 11.

Let me change the equation to, A1 x[0] + A2 x[1] + A3 x[2] + A4 x[3] >= 12, not necessarily it should be equal to RHS.
Then my expected output is [1,0,1,0], which equals to 13.